# Как правильно использовать MadelineProto (Telegran API)?

Tags: php, telegram

Подключил [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto), создал класс с данными учетки. Вроде бы все работает, т.к. вывелось много служебной инфы. Но страница грузится около полминуты. Не пойму, зачем мне выводится вся эта информация. А при вызове любого метода пишет:

```
Exception: This peer is not present in the internal peer database in PeerHandler.php:203
```

Может кто-то объяснить, как работать с MadelineProto, и что я делаю не так?

```
include 'phar.php';
$api_settings = [
    'authorization' => [
        'default_temp_auth_key_expires_in' => 86400,
        'rsa_keys'                         => массив_с_ключами
    ],
    'app_info' => [
        'api_id'   => ****,
        'api_hash' => *********************************
    ],
];
$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API($api_settings);
$messages_Chats = $MadelineProto->channels->getChannels(['id' => ["id_канала"]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ есть в официальной [документации](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/EXCEPTIONS.html)

Если коротко то "This peer is not present in the internal peer database: this error means you have tried sending a message to a peer that does not exist or is not present in MadelineProto’s internal peer database..." Другими словами проблема с передаваемым id.

Для меня на текущий момент срабатывает только один вариант идентификации группы это invitelink, хотя в доках написано что можно использовать и id и @name, я получаю такую же ошибку.

Вот так у меня работает:

```
$data = $MadelineProto->channels->getChannels(['id' => ['https://t.me/joinchat/xxxxxx']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Лично я особо не вдавался в то, как это настроить через файл конфигурации, а просто скопировал в исполнительный файл функцию подключения с документации, заполнил все необходимые поля и скрипт сам всё создал. 
Как я понял, твоя сессия сохраняется в файле "session.madeline" (в той же папке, что и исполнительный файл) и больше авторизации она не требует.

[Getting started](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/) 
Дальше, просто копируешь нужную функция из документации и работаешь уже с их данными